# How to run other bash scripts on YAD button click?

Tags: yad

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# YAD GUI to the set of Shell Linux script

 frmdata=$(yad --title "Input SRA accession number" --form --field
"SRA ID")


 frmaddr=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $1 }')


  echo $frmaddr > SRAIds.txt files=$(yad --width 100 --height 100
--title "Choose the action you want to be done" \
   --text="  Please enter what to do:" \
   --button="Download Files":"./fetch_sra_yad_zenity.sh"
\ #  calling the other bash script on the button click

   --button="Run alignment" \
   --button="Process variant calling" \
   --button="Cancel" \
   --on-top \
   --center \ )

ret=$?

[[ $ret -eq 1 ]] && exit 0
```

Need to run .sh scripts on relevant button clicks, without disappearing of buttons. How to fix that? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should look like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
# YAD GUI to the set of Shell Linux script

frmdata=$(yad --title "Input SRA accession number" /
--form --field "SRA ID")

frmaddr=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $1 }')

echo $frmaddr > SRAIds.txt

files=$(yad --width 100 --height 100 \
--title "Choose the action you want to be done" \
--text="Please enter what to do:" \
--button="Download Files:bash -c ./fetch_sra_yad_zenity.sh" \ 
--button="Run alignment" \
--button="Process variant calling" \
--button="Cancel" \
--on-top \
--center)

ret=$?

[[ $ret -eq 1 ]] && exit 0
```

As you can see, I added:

```
bash -c
```

to your script and it runs commands.
To be more exact that line should look like that:

```
--button='Download Files:bash - "./fetch_sra_yad_zenity.sh"'
```

it's because sometimes you may need to run a command with spaces or even some commands - thus they have to be in quotation marks.